# android form to php, php file not sending fields inputted in android form

Tags: php, android, email

I'm beginning to learn android programming and I'm completely newbie to php.

Before posting this question, I have tried all the answers related to it and none are working for me, so I decided to post a new question.

I have an application in which a user inputs a form and the contents of it get emailed to me.

I receive the email successfully, but the strings defined in php only. I also want the input from the user also to get delivered to my email.

Kindly check the php code and the java code below and suggest a suitable suggestion.

Email Received:

"First Name: Last Name: Your Email: Your Phone:"

without the user input in android form. :(

email2.php

```
<?php

$ed1=$_POST['fname'];
$ed2=$_POST['lname'];
$ed3=$_POST['email'];
$ed4=$_POST['phone'];
$to="ab5593@gmail.com";
$subject="android_email";
$from="$ed3";
$body="First Name:" .$ed1."\n Last Name:" .$ed2. "\n Your Email:".$ed3."\n Your Phone:"     .$ed4."\n";
$header="From :".$from."\n";

if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$header))
{
    echo "Thank you";
}
else
{
    echo"Try Again";
}

?>
```

FormActivity.java

```
package com.example.getpost;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FormActivity extends Activity {
    TextView txtvw;
    String text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

        txtvw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text = "";

        postData();
    }

    public void postData(){  
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.amit.comeze.com/email2.php");  
        EditText ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText ed3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        EditText ed4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", ed1.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", ed2.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", ed3.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", ed4.getText().toString()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);

            int current = 0;

            while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                baf.append((byte)current);
            }  

            /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            text = new String(baf.toByteArray());
            txtvw.setText(text);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}
```

Also when the form gets opened in android the "ThankYou" message is shown at startup even when the form is empty and I guess the mail also has not been sent.

I need the thankyou message to appear after the user presses the submit button on the form and also all the validation errors (not coded in php code given) to appear after the user presses the submit button.

Looking forward for your valuable suggestions which will help me greatly and would be appreciated more than that. 
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of problems in your code:

First, you can't do network stuff on the main thread. It has been said thousands of times here, to do so you need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for example.
As I've seen, you followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) to make your post request. Copy the exact same code inside the `doInBackground` of your AsyncTask.

Second, you are putting your post data function on onCreate, which is a function called when the activity is started, before user can interact with your app, that's why it is sending an empty form to your php code. To fix that, you should only initialize your views on onCreate.

```
public void postData(){   
EditText ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText ed3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
EditText ed4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
}
```

And maybe put a button to send all this info calling the execute method of the asyncTask (See the link above to understand how AsyncTask works).

I think after that you will be able to make your "app" work !

Hope it helps.

Comment: AsyncTask is really a timesaver... and DoInBackground() is the must implement in code. Thanks you brought it to my notice.

Comment: I followed the Asynctask Tutorial from here - mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example. I get the code work correctly and the toast also appears as coded. i modified the php file as below to receive the contents in my email as below but i dont receive the email. can you put light on this.. `<?php // receive data from app's http request $data=$_POST["myHttpData"]; $subject="AsyncTask"; $to="ab5593@gmail.com"; $body="First Name: .$data."; if(mail($to,$subject,$body)) { echo "SENT"; } else { echo"TRY AGAIN"; } ?>`

Comment: Hey amit, glad I could help. I'd suggest you posting a new question here on SO under the php tag, so more experienced people on that matter can help you !